# Inconstent foreign key in MariaDB 10.2

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, mariadb, innodb

It looks like I am facing a foreign-key constraint fault. It's very weird, never see anything like that.

You can see that item is referenced in `STUDIO_STAGE_ITEM_PARSE_TASKS`, it must exist in `STUDIO_STAGE_ITEMS` but it does not.

How can MariaDB behave like that?

We use MariaDB 10.2 in AWS RDS.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                                                      |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.20                                                     |
| protocol_version        | 10                                                         |
| slave_type_conversions  |                                                            |
| version                 | 10.2.12-MariaDB-log                                        |
| version_comment         | MariaDB Server                                             |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                                                     |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                                                      |
| version_malloc_library  | jemalloc 3.3.1-0-g9ef9d9e8c271cdf14f664b871a8f98c827714784 |
| version_ssl_library     | OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015                             |
| wsrep_patch_version     | wsrep_25.21                                                |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show create table STUDIO_STAGE_ITEM_PARSE_TASKS;

CREATE TABLE `STUDIO_STAGE_ITEM_PARSE_TASKS` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uuid` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `stage_Item_uuid` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `database_uuid` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status_uuid` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `DATE_CREATED` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_UPDATED` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `metadata` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_STAGE_ITEM_PARSE_TASKS_ITEM` (`stage_Item_uuid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_STAGE_ITEM_PARSE_TASK_UUID` (`uuid`),
  KEY `FK_STAGE_ITEM_PARSE_TASK_ATASK` (`status_uuid`),
  KEY `FK_STAGE_ITEM_PARSE_TASK_db` (`database_uuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_STAGE_ITEM_PARSE_TASK_ATASK` FOREIGN KEY (`status_uuid`) REFERENCES `STUDIO_ASYNC_TASKS` (`uuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_STAGE_ITEM_PARSE_TASK_ST_ITEM` FOREIGN KEY (`stage_Item_uuid`) REFERENCES `STUDIO_STAGE_ITEMS` (`uuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_STAGE_ITEM_PARSE_TASK_db` FOREIGN KEY (`database_uuid`) REFERENCES `partner` (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3569 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 


mysql> show create table STUDIO_STAGE_ITEMS;
CREATE TABLE `STUDIO_STAGE_ITEMS` (
  `uuid` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `database_uuid` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status_uuid` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_Size` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `file_Name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `raw_Items_Count` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `parsed_Items_Count` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `fileId` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `matched_Items_Count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `newly_Added_Items_Count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `DATE_CREATED` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_UPDATED` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`),
  KEY `fk_015_db` (`database_uuid`),
  KEY `fk_017_status` (`status_uuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_015_db` FOREIGN KEY (`database_uuid`) REFERENCES `partner` (`uuid`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_017_status` FOREIGN KEY (`status_uuid`) REFERENCES `STUDIO_ASYNC_TASKS` (`uuid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |


mysql> select * from STUDIO_STAGE_ITEM_PARSE_TASKS where uuid = '532cc618-5cab-4eae-a934-d3744644dc1e';
+------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
| id   | uuid                                 | stage_Item_uuid                      | database_uuid                        | status_uuid                          | active | DATE_CREATED        | DATE_UPDATED | metadata |
+------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
| 3560 | 532cc618-5cab-4eae-a934-d3744644dc1e | 63ffcb60-07c6-4e5a-aedc-89904f13c708 | 63086f0e-a0ea-45a2-ad1c-6096edc1b5a1 | 4cdad25b-2fd1-11e9-aa5f-02427e6aefff |       | 2019-02-13 20:52:39 | NULL         | {}       |
+------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------+---------------------+--------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from STUDIO_STAGE_ITEMS where uuid = '63ffcb60-07c6-4e5a-aedc-89904f13c708';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue : see [this MariaDB 10.2 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=67de7c8ee94468a2ce01e81ff599b671)

Comment: maybe someone did a simple `set session foreign_key_checks=0; delete * from whatever;`?

Comment: @fancyPants Application does not do it, and there is no client except application.

Comment: How exactly did the tables get their values? Because typically FK constraints are only checked on certain events. Also, the strings that are input & output by your question code are not necessarily the strings in the database. Eg there can be unprintable characters. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy If I had any MCVE I would not be here :)
Data gets to tables from JDBC inserts from application, nothing special. Strings are produced by program, they are uuid values.

Comment: Your claims are contradicted by your observations, so why believe them? Instrument your code & confirm them.

Comment: What do the UUIDs look like?  "Normal" ones are 36 characters of ascii.

Comment: @philipxy Indeed I am confirming all possible ways on my side. Here I just for good guesses. From what I dug by now, it's related to AWS RDS MultiAZ deployment when there is no transactional annotation on code. It looks like RDS "balances" request somehow based on metadata of session and it does not reach master.